# UWP Calendar Date Picker and Time Picker binding to one date time

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to get a calender date picker and time picker binded (MVVM Light x:Bind) to one datetime object but im just getting frustrated as nothing I try is working.  I've tried using converters which convert the datetime to datetimeoffset for the calender date property (This works) but the time picker seems to infinitly keep calling its converter which returns the timespan on the datetime?

I know it will be something stupid and really simple but im just getting frustrated with UWP and how the simplest of things takes an age to work out because lack of documentation.

Is there a simple sample of this type of control or nuget package i can be pointed to so I can view it and get my head around?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like x:Bind is the source of my problems, changing to Binding seems to fix all my issues

Comment: Can you provide the code answer? Im looking for a simple bind to one DateTime from date and time picker.